# How to use JsonReader for parsing this complicated json given below in android?

Tags: android, json, jsonreader, large-data

Here I have nested array in json response.

1. I have given indexes response.  How can I parse this response using JsonReader?  I have used JsonReader because of large amount of json.
2. I want to start from index 8 and want to go up to n indexes. How can I do that using JsonReader?

   ```
   dt_ReturnedTables[14]
   |
   V
   0   ->  [92]
   1   ->  [6115]
   2   ->  [64]
   3   ->  [14]
   4   ->  [3]
   5   ->  [1]
   6   ->  [3]
   7   ->  [5]
   8   ->  [89]
   9   ->  [3]
   10  ->  [2]
   11  ->  [1]
   12  ->  [174]
   13  ->  [522]

   ObjRetArgs : null
   Status  :   1
   Message :   Account Address Detail data retrieved successfully.`
   ```

Comment: have you read `android.util.JsonReader` documentation? it has even small example how to use it, if you read you most likely found yout that you can skip only the whole value e.g. object or array, not the array slice

Comment: Yes i have read this doc but when i am trying to parse from  0 and i reached to index at 4. i got all the data perfectly but from index 5 i got blank array.its also happened at index 6 and so on.

Comment: what is your code and input json data?

Comment: Please check this link http://pastebin.com/5D4g9JVd